# Trying to get the list box to change the background color of the form c#

Tags: c#, listbox, background-color

Okay, so I'm trying to get the items in the `ListBox` to change the background color of the form. So, if the user were to click the option yellow, it would automatically change the background color of the form. This is the code that I have written.

```
private void listbox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selected_color;
    if (listbox.SelectedIndex != -1)
    { 
        colorSel = colorsLstBx.SelectedIndex.ToString();

        switch (selected_color)
        {
            case "Yellow":
                this.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                break;
            //othercolors
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: You can actually avoid the if clause by using the `SelectedIndexChanged` event and the switch case also becomes unnecessary when you populate your `colorsLstBx` with `Color`s. This way you can just directly assign the `Color`. Have a look on my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has several flaws.
In your code you use two different listboxes: listbox & colorsLstBx. 
Next you convert the selectedIndex to a string which is then "0", "1", etc. and not "Yellow", "Red" etc.

This works for me:

```
 private void listBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (listBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            var colorSel = listBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
            switch (colorSel)
            {
                case "Yellow":
                    this.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    break;
                //othercolors
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: And you probably don't want to rely on Click event of the listbox but on SelectedIndexChanged event of the listbox.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to switch to `selected_color` you should assign a value to it somewhere:

```
string selected_color;

switch (selected_color) // << at this point selected_color is null!
```

If your colours are in `colorsLstBx` you can populate it with `Color`s and assign them directly from the selected item in the `colorsLstBx_SelectedIndexChanged` event:

```
List<Color> ColorList = new List<Color>() { Color.Yellow, Color.Red};


public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.listBox1.DataSource = ColorList;
}


// if this event is fired you don't need to check whether an item is selected or not (no if-clause needed) 
private void colorsLstBx_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // just assign the selected item and no switching is needed
    this.BackColor = (Color)listBox1.SelectedItem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have declared string variable named 'selected_color' and assigned drop down item values to 'colorSel ' variable and again using 'selected_color' in switch case  use colorSel  in switch case

**NOTE** You Should use SelectedIndexChanged EVENT of a LIST BOX instead of click event